# bin/cake bake no result

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm following the `bookmark tutorial` for `ver3.0.`

I tried these commands:

```
bin/cake bake all users
bin/cake bake all bookmarks
bin/cake bake all tags
```

results were all `"Minimum PHP version: 5.4.16. You are using: 5.4.3"` and no controllers, views, models were created.

Can someone lead me to the right direction? I'm new to `CakePHP`.

I have PHP 5.5.12 installed on WAMP2.5. `php -v` gives "php5.4.3 on git".

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your PHP version?

Comment: Cake is telling the truth and @Steve is right, you need to upgrade PHP. Please note that depending on your system configuration, the PHP version in your shell may differ from the one you have in Apache.

Comment: Appreciate your help. It worked. Changed the Windows environment variable from PHP 4.4.3 to 5.5.12. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

if want run cake bake the first step
Windows 7

1. Select Computer from the Start menu
2. Choose System Properties from the context menu
3. Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
4. Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
5. In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding

   **C:\xampp\htdocs\App-file\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;**

### now can use

cake bake model all
cake bake controller all
cake bake Template all

Answer (score 1):

In case of Windows, the bake command: **bin\cake bake all** is used instead of **bin/cake bake all**

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade PHP to 5.5 or to 5.6, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in XAMPP with PHP 5.4.7. After updating XAMPP to the newer PHP version 5.6.8, I am able to `bake`.